# No JREs found in C:\\Program Files\java in Eclipse Scala IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

JDK 1.8 is already installed in Windows 10 64 bit system. I am trying to create a scala project in Eclipse Scala IDE. Is says "Unbound classpath container: JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8] in project.

While checking the Java build path-- Libraries-- JRE is coming outbound.

When I click to add JRE library, it has workspace default JRE (unbound)

While searching through preferences-- installed JRE--search. It gives no JREs.

If I try to add -- standard vm--directory ( JDK dir home). Ideally it should populate or detect all the jars but it doesn't detect.

Comment: The **ScalaIDE** for **Eclipse** has been deprecated for a couple of years now, you probably would want to use any other IDE, like **IntelliJ**.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried running the application as 'Administrator' and it ran successfully.

Comment: Sounds like the permissions for your installed copies of Java are not right.

Answer (score 0):

Select your project and right click--> Build Path --> Configure Build Path -->Select Libraries--> Add Library-->JRE System Library--> Add the installed JRE here.

And if the JRE library is not getting selected, check the environment variables- **JAVA_HOME and Path.**

And to see if the java is correctly installed, try hitting this from CMD
**java -version**